# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from: failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am using an external SOAP API, and I am getting this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/uetdsarizi?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/uetdsarizi?wsdl" "
```

The real problem is that sometimes it works just fine. For example, whenever I get this error, I just retype the same code into the page containing my script, and it works temporarily, then I get this error again.

This is my code :

```
 <?php
try{
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        // set some SSL/TLS specific options
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$soapclient = new SoapClient('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/uetdsarizi?wsdl',
    array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'login'    => '***',
        'password' => '***',
        'stream_context' => $context
    )
);
$param=array('wsuser'=>[
    'kullaniciAdi'=>'***',
    'sifre'=>'***'],
    'uetdsSeferReferansNo'=>'1'
    );

$response =$soapclient->bildirimOzeti($param);
$vars = $response -> return;
$sonucKodu = $vars -> sonucKodu;
echo $sonucKodu."\n";
print var_dump($response);
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo var_dump($e->getMessage());
  echo var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
   echo var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
}
?>
```

I need to get rid of this error permanently.